# "Wind turbine" Motor balance equations

Tags: electric-circuits, angular-momentum, electrical-resistance, torque, inductance

[image]

I have this model of a wind turbine with written balance equations.
I don't really understand the equation in the second line, I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what it means exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation
$$(J_R+J_M)\dot{\omega}=M_R-k_Mi_G=f_{Rotor}(v_{wind},\omega)-k_Mi_G$$
is the mechanical equation of motion in terms of [torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque).

- The left-hand side $(J_R+J_M)\dot{\omega}$ is essentially the [definition
  of torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque#Definition_and_relation_to_angular_momentum) ($\tau=J\dot{\omega}$) where $J$ is the [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)
  (of rotor and generator) and $\dot{\omega}$ is the angular acceleration.
- The right-hand side ($M_R-k_Mi_G$) is the torque,
  having two components:
  $M_R$ is the torque which the wind applies to the rotor.
  $-k_Mi_G$ is the torque from the electromagnetic effect
  by the electric current $i_G$.
  The minus sign is there because of [Lenz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law).
  (*The current induced [...] is directed [...] to exert a mechanical
  force which opposes the motion.*)

Comment: Thank you for your support, it's really helpful. Also what ist Frotor(Vwind,w) exactly?

Comment: @Mtein welcome. I don't know about $f_{Rotor}(v_{wind},\omega)$. It seems to be some characteristic function describing the rotor.